# Verifying that the composition of permutations $(1, 2, 3) \circ (3, 4, 5) = (1, 2, 4, 5, 3)$

Tags: permutations

I want to make sure the following equality is true:

$(1,2,3)\circ (3,4,5)= (1, 2, 4, 5, 3)$

I don't know how to check if that's true.

Thank You

Comment: What's the operation between those two brackets?

Comment: @JaideepKhare A composition. Let me edit my post

Answer (score 5):

You are close, but off bit a little bit. We see that in the product $(123)(345)$, we can check what the product is by considering each possible input, then following it through the function composition,

- $1\to1\to2$
- $2\to2\to3$
- $3\to4\to4$
- $4\to5\to5$
- $5\to3\to1$

Therefore, we have that $(123)(345) = (123)\circ(345) = (12345)$.

Edit: @Arthur reminded me that some use algebraic notation instead of function notation regarding multiplication of permutations. In the above computation, I assumed that $(123)(345)(x) = (123)[(345)(x)]$. Using the algebraic convention, we have that

- $1\to2\to2$
- $2\to3\to4$
- $4\to4\to5$
- $5\to5\to3$
- $3\to1\to1$

So $(123)(345) = (345)\circ(123)=(12453)$.

Comment: This depends on whether the permutations are applied right-to-left or left-to-right. If they're applied right-to-left, then this is the correct answer. If they're applied left-to-right, then the result in the original question is true. I usually apply them right-to-left, but since that seems to be the exact thing differentiating your answer form the OP's answer, I feel it deserves a mention.

Comment: Good point! I assumed that since Sylvester used the $\circ$ notation he was following right-to-left convention, but I'll edit my answer to address that. Thanks!